# Why can't I find backports-3.3.2 in any of the sources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run a Ruby on Rails Project. I installed RVM, set Ruby to be version 1.8.7, and got everything up and running except when I try to run `rackup` I get:

```
/Users/afrieden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `materialize': Could not find backports-3.3.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from /Users/afrieden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
from /Users/afrieden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
from /Users/afrieden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
from /Users/afrieden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
from /Users/afrieden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
from /Users/afrieden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
from /Users/afrieden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /Users/afrieden/Downloads/neo_visual_search-master/neovs_app.rb:2
from /Users/afrieden/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /Users/afrieden/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/afrieden/Downloads/neo_visual_search-master/config.ru:4
from /Users/afrieden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/afrieden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /Users/afrieden/Downloads/neo_visual_search-master/config.ru:0:in `new'
from /Users/afrieden/Downloads/neo_visual_search-master/config.ru:0
```

I tried `gem install Bundler` but it just reinstalled and I got the same error.

Has anyone seen this problem before?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install gem from source, write this in your Gemfile :

```
gem 'backports', :require => false
```

Or

```
gem "backports", :git => "https://github.com/marcandre/backports.git"
```

hope this will help. I think first one will work, if not try another one. Thanks